# Find $b$ and $c$ for $f(x)=\log(-x^2+bx+c) $

Tags: function-and-relation-composition, domain-theory

I have a function $f(x)=\log(-x^{2}+bx+c) $ and the domain of $f$ is $(1,3)$. I have to use this fact to find the values of $b$ and $c$. I thought about solving the inequality $1 < \log(-x^2+bx+c) < 3 $ but not sure about that approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality you have given would make the range of $f(x)$ be $(1,3)$. For the domain, you want $-x^2+bx+c>0$, and you would want to find $b$ and $c$ such that only for $x \in (1,3)$ would $-x^2+bx+c>0$.

Comment: Hint: to find such $b$ and $c$, consider the zeroes of $-x^2+bx+c$.

Comment: I'm still not sure what to do. I tried solving the inequality you suggested above, and I got $ c > -3$ and $ b>4$ but not sure what to do from here

Comment: Actually I get it now. I solved $ -x^{2} + bx + c = 0 $ then subbed in $1$ and $3$ individually and got the answer. Thank you

Comment: Exactly, you want 1 and 3 to be the zeroes of that quadratic. If you draw the quadratic with the correct $b$ and $c$, its clear why 1 and 3 need to be the zeroes (they're the boundary).